# Magento Shipment Create (programatically) - odd bug

Tags: php, magento

I use the following function to generate shipment for given order, sku/qty:

```
function CreateShipment($order_info)
{
    // Anticipate Error
    try
    {
        // Load Magento Order
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->loadByIncrementId($order_info->MagentoOrderIncrementId);

        // Load Magento Order Lines
        $order_items = $order->getItemsCollection();

        // Parse Despatch Lines
        $despatch_skus = array();
        foreach ($order_info->DespatchLines as $DespatchLine) {
            $despatch_skus[$DespatchLine->Sku] = $DespatchLine->Qty;
        }

        // Build Item Qtys
        $item_qtys = array();
        foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {
            if (array_key_exists($order_item->getSku(), $despatch_skus)) {
                $item_qtys[$order_item->getItemId()] = 
                    $despatch_skus[$order_item->getSku()];
            } else {
                $item_qtys[$order_item->getItemId()] = 0;
            }
        }

        // Create Shipment
        $shipment = $order->prepareShipment($item_qtys);
        $shipment->register();
        $shipment->sendEmail(false)
                 ->setEmailSent(false)
                 ->save();
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                 ->addObject($shipment)
                 ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                 ->save();

        // Finished
        $order = null;
        $shipment = null;
        $transactionSave = null;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        // Log Error
    }
    return false;
}
```

where, **$order_info** is a object that looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [MagentoOrderIncrementId] => 100010039
    [DespatchLines] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Sku] => VCF001
                    [Qty] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

The function returns true, however the order in magento does not show "Shipped: 1" - take a look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj0da.png

However, if I clicked on "Shipments" tab, I can see the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epI2m.png

So it looks like the shipment did get created. If I go into the entry, I see my sku and qty: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIkUY.png

Any idea why the order is not getting updated properly with the shipment I just created?

Note* If I use the "Ship" button on top right, it will allow me to ship the item again and this time it works correctly (when I do it within admin U.I). It's just not working as expected via the function code I posted above.

Any tips/hints/advice will be most appreciated. Regards, Latheesan.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed by adding this line after "$transactionSave" code block:

```
$order->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best practice, I have added these two lines that worked for me:

```
$orderItem->setQtyShipped(1); 
$orderItem->save();
```